# HTMLTidy - style sheets require testing

Tags: html, css, firefox, htmltidy

I changed the accessibility level in HTMLTidy's options, and now I'm getting an "access warning", which says

```
Access: [6.1.1.1]: style sheets require testing (link) (Priority 1)
```

The "solution" is remarkably unhelpful:

[image]

How to clean this up, the **right** way (not by toggling a setting or turning off an option)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to clean it up, because the warning refers to an issue that cannot be tested automatically (at the present state of the art, if ever). The warning is issued by Tidy whenever the page uses style sheets. It is a very general reminder indeed.

The message is basically this: turn off style sheets, and check that the page still works. On Firefox, you can easily switch off style sheets (via the View menu; using Web Developer Extension, you can also switch off individual style sheets).

Note that Tidy’s reference to “WAI 1.0” (i.e., WCAG 1.0) is outdated; WCAG 1.0 was succeeded by [WCAG 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/) in 2008, and the HTML Techniques document has been superseded by [Techniques for WCAG 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/). WCAG 2.0 is very different from WCAG 1.0.

Comment: Ahhh!  So all of my nice, tidy pages now scream out access warnings.  Rats.

Comment: Well, the purpose of running checks is to detect errors and problems (in order to fix them if needed), not to get clean reports. ☺ But many checkers, especially accessibility-related, issue so many warnings and recommendations to check things out “manually” that their usefulness is questionable.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly why I use Tidy - to fix empty tags, badly formed XHTML, etc...but with this change it is indeed moving into the "questionable" category.  Ah well I suppose I'll just turn off the option (back to square one :p ) Thanks for the help.